# PhpStorm and IdeaVim - shortcut to complete line?

Tags: vim, phpstorm, ideavim

I'm using the current [PHP Storm EAP (138.1505)](http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2014/08/phpstorm-8-eap-138-1505/#comments) and [IdeaVim 0.35](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?id=164).

Suppose I just want to type:

```
print_r($foo);
```

- I press `i` to go into Vim insert mode.
- I type `p` `r` and I can choose `print_r` via the autocomplete.
- It'll add open and close braces `()` for me.
- I start typing my variable, it'll let me autocomplete that too.
- At this stage I have `print_r($foo)` with my cursor positioned before the closing bracket.

What I'd like now is a single key combination that'll finish the line for me - i.e. add a semi-colon and a carriage return.  At the moment I either have to type `);[return]` by hand as if the autocomplete wasn't there, or for some reason I've got in the habit of doing `esc` to leave insert mode then `A` to continue at the end of the line and `;[return][esc]`to finish it off, which is even longer.

Any better way?

Comment: What about `<End>;<Return>`?

Comment: @romainl that does work; although not everyone will be using a keyboard with a dedicated end key (and personally I prefer the combination Kent suggested.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use PHP Storm. but I do use Intellij + ideavim.

Here I can press `Ctrl-Shift-Enter` to complete a line. It is a kind of default setting. You can find it under `menu: Edit: complete current statement`

You may want to give it a try.

Comment: Thanks (for Mac users it's Cmd-Shift-Enter). Doesn't appear to be in the PhpStorm menus, for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line to `~/.ideavimrc`:

```
imap <C-e> <Esc>A;<CR>
```

Replace `<C-e>` with your desired key.